# How to pass a video file to worker function in Heroku (Flask)

Tags: heroku, flask, amazon-s3, file-upload, redis

**Context**

I have a web dyno which receives a video file with the intention of applying a computer vision algorithm to return an analysis. The algorithm takes about 10 seconds to run. My current method is to process it with the web dyno. The whole thing is pretty fast. The user doesn't have to wait any more than a minute.

**What's not working**

But of course, tying up the web dyno is a bad idea. And some users have gotten timeouts... So I tried implementing redis to pass the job to a worker dyno.

```
@application.route('/video', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def video():
    video_file = request.files['videoData']
    job = q.enqueue_call(
        func=run_analysis, args=(video_file), result_ttl=5000
    )
    return json.dumps(job.id)
```

But this gives me an error
`TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object` and I understand why.

In my dev env, I can save the video to the filesystem and pass the file path only, but this doesn't work in production as the web dyno's file system is ephemeral and the worker won't see the file.

So I'm looking for the fastest way to get the video file across. Speed is of the essence here, as the user is waiting for their video to be processed.

**What I've tried**

I've tried S3 (uploading direct from client and downloading in the worker) but it made the whole process way slower. First of all, it takes longer to upload to S3 than to my Heroku endpoint. Second of all, I have to then download it to the worker which takes a while as well. I don't really need to keep the file, so it's a very inefficient work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku dynos are completely isolated containers, that is why they cannot share file system as you want. But if you'll host them on another hosting like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) or Amazon, you'll be able to access files you stored by Flask from the other workers instantly (or almost instantly - don't forget to create a copy of temp-file, Flask or WSGI should delete it after response sent).

Another option is to find the fastest way of "transporting" video-data (not always file) to a worker. You can do it using:

- **queue** - put whole file to a queue. Method is not recommended, but still ok, if video files are really small.
- **in-memory database** - save file to some in-memory database (e.g. Redis). They have a lot of mechanisms to quickly transport data between servers or processes (cons: expensive on Heroku)
- **database** - save file to a general purpose database (e.g. Postgresql), that will do the same as Redis, but it is able to work with bigger data cheaper, though a bit slower.
- **WebSockets** or even **Unix-socket** - you can have one worker to which Flask can connect to, send file and return http-response. That "listener" will actually start task. It can either save video to a file and provide path to еру next worker (but it should always be on the same dyno as the rest workers are) or provide data directly using args, "fork", threading, subprocessing, etc.
  You can start with [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
  But remember, that you need to configure server-to-server connection - between webapp and worker that should list it in loop or separate thread. Not Javascript in browser, which potentially is also option - start task and upload file directly to worker.
  **P.S.** there are no 30sec. timeouts on Heroku for WebSockets :)

Comment: Great, thank you for your time! Just two quick follow up questions: (1) The video files can be 20-50MB. Will that be too heavy for a database like postgres?, (2) Do you know of any resources/tutorials that could help me understand your last point a bit better? I'm not familiar with websockets.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare (1) No, for Postgres - not too heavy. It may be too heavy for Redis. (2) I believe you can start with Flask-SocketIO official documentation and examples. Updated answer with more details for both.